# How do I connect bower components with sails.js?

Tags: javascript, dependency-management, bower, sails.js

I'd like to be able to install Javascript dependencies through **bower** and use them in a [sails.js](http://sailsjs.org) app, but I can't figure out a way to do this with out just copying an pasting files from the `bower_components` folder to the **Sails** assets folder.

Ideally I think I'd like to use `requirejs` and point to the **bower components** in the `main.js` file. I may be trying to pound a square peg in a round hole, please let me know if so. Any thoughts on managing `components/libraries` with Sails are welcome.

Answer (score 42):

In Sails 0.10 the 'assets/linker' directory no longer exists, however I found a lead on simple solution that gives some automation to the bower -> asset linker workflow while also allowing some granular control over what exactly ends up getting linked.

The solution is adding [grunt-bower](https://github.com/curist/grunt-bower) to your Sails.js **compileAssets** task

```
grunt.registerTask('compileAssets', [
    'clean:dev',
    'bower:dev',
    'jst:dev',
    'less:dev',
    'copy:dev',
    'coffee:dev'
]);
```

Then configure your grunt-bower task like so (as **tasks/config/bower.js**):

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.config.set('bower', {
    dev: {
        dest: '.tmp/public',
        js_dest: '.tmp/public/js',
        css_dest: '.tmp/public/styles'
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-bower');

};
```

This will automatically copy your bower js and css files to the proper place for Sail's asset linker to find and automatically add to your project's layout template.  Any other js or css files will still automatically be added after your bower files.

However this is still no silver bullet as this setup has 2 big caveats to it:

1 - The files that are added through bower-grunt have to be listed in bower.json's **main** array.  If you see a file isn't being loaded you would expect to be, you must either edit that packages bower.json file OR add the dependency manually through grunt-bower's **packageSpecific** options.

2 - The order of bower files in the asset linker is currently alphabetical.  My only recourse to adjust this order so far is tinkering around with an additional grunt task to manually re-order files prior to the rest of Sail's **compileAssets** task.  However this one I'm confident there is something grunt-bower could do [by supporting package copy ordering](https://github.com/curist/grunt-bower/issues/19).

Comment: To manage the order of scripts, simply edit `tasks/pipeline.js` at `var jsFilesToInject = []`

Comment: This was working great, until version `0.15.1` of grunt-bower.  Something has changed that prevents the bower_components from being copied over.

Comment: I think it must be fixed now, because as of today it is working for me with grunt-bower 0.16.0.

Answer (score 33):

**Note**: the following answer is no longer completely relevant to the current version of SailsJS because there is no support for the linker folder as of SailsJS 0.10.

See: [Sails not generating linker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23704035/sails-not-generating-linker)

**Original answer:**

I was able to figure out a solution for this, which is actually pretty simple. I had not realized you could configure where bower places it's files.

Create a .bowerrc file and change the directory where bower components are installed, in the case of Sailjs they should be put into the assets folder.

```
/*
 * Create a file called .bowerrc and put the following in it.
 * This file should be in the root directory of the sails app.
 */

 {
   "directory": "assets/linker/bower_components"
 }
```

Sails will then use grunt to copy them to the .tmp/public/assets folder whenever a file is change. If you don't wish to have sails continually deleting and then recopying those files you can exclude them in the grunt file.

```
/* 
 * This is not necessary, but if you have a lot of components and don't want
 * them constantly being deleted and copied at every file change you can update
 * your Gruntfile.js with the below.
 */

 clean: {
   dev: ['.tmp/public/**',
         '!.tmp/public',
         '!.tmp/public/bower_components/**'],
   build: ['www']
 },
```

One tip on using requirejs with sails. By default you will get an error from the socket.io file since sails will load it without using requirejs. This will throw an error since socket.io supports amd style loading, more details here http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch.

The simplest way to fix this is to just comment out the lines near the end of the socket.io.js.

```
/*
 * Comment the below out in the file assets/js/socket.io.js, if using requirejs
 * and you don't want to modify the default sails setup or socket.io.
 */

 if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
   define([], function () { return io; });
 }
```

The other way would be to recode the sails files in assets/js named "socket.io.js", "sails.io.js" and app.js to be amd modules.

Comment: This answer is now somewhat outdated.

Answer (score 11):

The simplest way I've found of achieving this is simply to add the individual Bower components to your `tasks/pipeline.js` file. For example, here's how you might add Modernizr:

```js
// Client-side javascript files to inject in order
// (uses Grunt-style wildcard/glob/splat expressions)
var jsFilesToInject = [

  // Load sails.io before everything else
  'js/dependencies/sails.io.js',

  // Dependencies like jQuery, or Angular are brought in here
  'js/dependencies/**/*.js',

  // =========================================================
  // Modernizr:
  'bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js',
  // =========================================================

  // All of the rest of your client-side js files
  // will be injected here in no particular order.
  'js/**/*.js'
];
```

A link to `bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js` then gets inserted in the `<!--SCRIPTS-->` placeholder in your layout template, and it also gets minified, etc, when you run `sails lift --prod`.

Comment: Yeah this is the answer for v0.11

Comment: +1 for this answer. Adding a `.bowerrc` with  `{"directory": "assets/bower_components"}` will help as well

Comment: Really like this solution and adding the .bowerrc as it's very clean, straight forward and integrates well.

Comment: .bowerrc is by far the simplest solution and works beautifully. Should be marked as accepted answer!

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for my late.

I think include bower_components in linker it's a bad idea, because when you will lift sails, everything in it will be copied in .tmp and include in  tags.
For example, if you have include Angular with bower, you will have two inclusions in your script: one for angular.js and one for angular.min.js. And having both is a mistake.

Here is my solution on my projects :

- I have created a folder bower_component in my root directory.
- I have added this line in my Gruntfile.js in the array files in copy:dev

  { '.tmp/public/linker/js/angular.js': './bower_components/angular/angular.js' }

And for each files I want to include, I need to manually add a new line in this array. I haven't find an another automatic solution. If someone finds a better solution... ;)

Comment: This can be a solution also.

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one approach to hooking up SailsJS and Bower.

A package for SailsJS that integrates Bower via a custom generator exists here: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-generate-bower

There is one for Gulp as well.

Comment: Link-only answers are highly discouraged here because the links may become dead in the future. I suggest you edit your answer with quotes from the sources you cite.