# SailsJS Linker (Grunt) Ignore files (Gruntfile.js)

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, sails.js

I am using bower for asset management. The Bootstrap bower repo is coming with a Gruntfile.js.

Is there a way to exclude this from the linker?

I have tried:

```
var jsFilesToInject = [
     '!**Gruntfile.js',
//     ...
]
```

But it's not working - am I putting this string in the wrong spot?

### Generated HTML and Error

[image]

### File Structure

[image]

**P.S.** I followed this guide to get here: [StackOverFlow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18139290/how-do-i-connect-bower-components-with-sailsjs) and ran `bower install bootstrap` and `bower install angular`.

Comment: can you post your whole `jsFilesToInject` it seems like you have a problem of path, we can see that you load both `angular.js` and `angular.min.js`

Comment: @Wallter, it seems that there is a problem with Sails regarding excludes, see https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/2375.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in the current sails frontend generator. I have [submitted a PR](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-generate-frontend/pull/21), but existing applications will have to be fixed manually, since the generator is only executed once.

The issue is in the end of the current `pipeline.js` file, in the section that actually exports the settings. At the moment it goes like this:

```
// pipeline.js

//... Defined rules ...

module.exports.cssFilesToInject = cssFilesToInject.map(function(path) {
  return '.tmp/public/' + path;
});
module.exports.jsFilesToInject = jsFilesToInject.map(function(path) {
  return '.tmp/public/' + path;
});
module.exports.templateFilesToInject = templateFilesToInject.map(function(path) {
  return 'assets/' + path;
});
```

As you can see it prepends the relative path to the `tmp` folder or the `assets` folder for templates. This results in the rule
`!js/foo.js` in `.tmp/public/!js/foo.js`, which will probably not match anything.

The solution is to replace the block above in `pipeline.js` with the following:

```
module.exports.cssFilesToInject = cssFilesToInject.map(function(path) {
  var tmpPath = '.tmp/public/';
  if (path.substring(0,1) == '!')
    return '!' + tmpPath + path.substring(1);
  return tmpPath + path;
});
module.exports.jsFilesToInject = jsFilesToInject.map(function(path) {
  var tmpPath = '.tmp/public/';
  if (path.substring(0,1) == '!')
    return '!' + tmpPath + path.substring(1);
  return tmpPath + path;
});
module.exports.templateFilesToInject = templateFilesToInject.map(function(path) {
  var tmpPath = 'assets/';
  if (path.substring(0,1) == '!')
    return '!' + tmpPath + path.substring(1);
  return tmpPath + path;
});
```

This will check if the given rule starts with an `!` and prepend it correctly, so `!js/foo.js` will result in `!.tmp/public/js/foo.js` that will correctly match.

**The exclusions have to be set AFTER the result set was created.** This is according to [grunt's documentation](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns). So for your case it would be:

```
var jsFilesToInject = [
     //...
     '!**Gruntfile.js',
]
```

Answer (score 5):

A working configuration for me has been the following :

- put the `bower_components` folder one level up, directly in the `assets` folder.
- put all your app related files in the `linker` folder

  ```
  | .bowerrc
  | assets/
  |-- bower_components/
  |---- bootstrap/
  |------ dist/
  |-------- bootstrap.js
  |---- angular/
  |-- linker/
  |---- js/
  |------ sails.io.js
  |------ socket.io.js
  |---- styles/
  |---- templates/
  ```

In your `Gruntfile.js` have a `jsFileToInject` setup like so

```
    var jsFilesToInject = [
        // Below, as a demonstration, you'll see the built-in dependencies
        // linked in the proper order order
        // Bring in the socket.io client
        'linker/js/socket.io.js',

        // then beef it up with some convenience logic for talking to Sails.js
        'linker/js/sails.io.js',

        // jQuery and plugins
        'bower_components/jquery/jquery.js',

        // Bootstrap
        'bower_components/bootstrap/dist/bootstrap.js',

        // Angular
        'bower_components/angular/angular.js',

        // App file that needs to load first
        'linker/js/app.js',

        // All of the rest of your app scripts imported here
        'linker/**/*.js'
    ];
```

And in the `.bowerrc` at the root of your project, you put

```
    {
        "directory": "assets/bower_components"
    }
```

Comment: this is a good answer, probably one of the best i've seen so far.. Only thing that sucks is you have to manually specify all of your `JSFilesToInject`. One tip is if you're using requireJs you can use the `grunt-contrib-requirejs` to do some of this for you.

Comment: I know this solution exists. But I think it is much nicer to just have the bower_components in the linker folder because when you run bower install, it will automatically add this to your project (seems to keep with the node/sails theme of making life easier)

Comment: You can add a .bowerrc file at the root of your project with this: `{
    "directory": "assets/bower_components"
}` this will tell bower where to put your dependencies.

Comment: I've added the `.bowerrc` part to the answer.