# Configure Bower with Sails.js 0.10

Tags: node.js, sails.js, bower

I installed grunt-bower module and followed up the below link:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22456574/194345

but still not able to access js or css files placed in assets folder.

I installed jquery with bower which is in "assets\lib\jquery\dist\jquery.js" but in browser, tried following URL to access it:

```
http://localhost:1337/js/jquery.js

http://localhost:1337/lib/js/jquery.js

http://localhost:1337/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js
```

it always displays not found.

What is the correct path?

Answer (score 4):

I think you may not have fully implemented the solution from the link you posted, specifically the part about configuring the `grunt-bower` task.  I've edited that otherwise excellent answer to be a but more clear--you need to wrap the configuration in a function and save it as **tasks/config/bower.js**:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.config.set('bower', {
    dev: {
        dest: '.tmp/public',
        js_dest: '.tmp/public/js',
        css_dest: '.tmp/public/styles'
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-bower');

};
```

Then, next time you lift Sails, **jquery.js** will be copied to **.tmp/public/js** and therefore be available at `http://localhost:1337/js/jquery.js`.

Comment: can I open .tmp folder after lifting on windows to make sure files are there?