# Bower to Sails - What have I missed?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm, sails.js, bower

I have been struggling with this and would appreciate any help you can offer.
I have a fresh install of [sails](http://sailsjs.org) and have configured it to use handlebars. It lift beautifully.

I have installed bower using

```
npm i sails-generate-bower
```

After a quick

```
bower install bootstrap --save
```

I can see that it has generated the core bootstrap files in

```
/bower_components //the root of my project
```

What do I do now to ensure that upon lift I have the Bootstrap files in the correct places?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I connect bower components with sails.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18139290/how-do-i-connect-bower-components-with-sails-js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Their are many ways to do this.

You either configure your asset pipeline `config/tasks/pipeline.js` or [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18139290/how-do-i-connect-bower-components-with-sails-js/22456574#22456574) a similar question and valid answer.

[Documentation](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/Assets/TaskAutomation.html)